# Is python way of declaring a big two dimensional array more expensive than c++?

Tags: list, runtime

The original leetcode problem is :
**Longest Palindromic Substring**

*Given a string S, find the longest palindromic substring in S. You may assume that the maximum length of S is 1000, and there exists one unique longest palindromic substring.*

I programed in python, using a 2d DP way and Always got Time Limit Exceeded. While implemented the same idea with Cpp, it got passed easily.

I have spent hours on this, what would be the part in python responding to 
the high cost compared to Cpp.

**I searched and know for sure reversed() would be safe, it won't make copies. I am thinking about whether it might be caused by the way python declare the dp matrix?**

Anybody can tell what's wrong in the python version?

Python

```
class Solution:
# @param s, a string
# @return a string
def longestPalindrome(self, s):
    st = 0
    maxl = 0
    dp = [[False]*1000 for i in xrange(1000)]
    for i in reversed(xrange(len(s))):
        for j in xrange(i,len(s)):
            if s[i] == s[j] and (i+1>j-1 or dp[i+1][j-1] ):
                dp[i][j] = True
                if j-i+1 > maxl:
                    st = i
                    maxl = j-i+1

    return s[st:st+maxl]
```

C++

```
class Solution {
public:
string longestPalindrome(string s) {
    int start = 0, maxLen = 1, n = s.size();
    bool isPal[1000][1000] = {false};
    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
        for(int j=i; j<n; j++) {
            if((i+1>j-1 || isPal[i+1][j-1]) && s[i]==s[j]) {
                isPal[i][j] = true;
                if(j-i+1>maxLen) {
                    maxLen = j-i+1;
                    start = i;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return s.substr(start,maxLen);
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

From scipy mailing list [discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-dev/2005-December/004647.html),

"comparison operations are potentially expensive for general Python objects where they are relatively very cheap for numeric arrays".

If you want a better performance, use a dedicated numerical library like [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/)/[scipy](http://scipy.org/).

If you want a deeper answer on Python performance compared to a compiled language, maybe it would be worth a separate question on Python internals or its interpreter.

BTW, don't you need to indent before the function def in your [class definition](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax)?

This answers the question of the performance of your complete code. If you want to know exactly the performance of memory allocation in Python, then test only the dedicated part from your code and write whether it works or not.

Another approach for better performance is to use Cython. [Here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) is a thorough description on Python overhead compared to C.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. Basically my question should be  : Is the following line of code : "dp = [[False]*1000 for i in xrange(1000)]" in python is a expensive way to define a 2 dimension list compare to a 2 dimension array declaration in C++ or Java . Because I see a lot copying going on there

Comment: @shiyuDong - I think that you reserve the list right. The main drawback is inside your cycle (which should be solved using other methods, not directly those of the language). Sorry if my answer wasn't straightforward enough. Also, yes, almost everything in Python is more expensive than in C++ because they are very different languages w.r.t. performance.